# Cassandra across multiple Azure datacentres

Tags: azure, cassandra

trying to figure out how to create Cassandra cluster in Azure across more than one datacentre.

I am not much interested in Cassandra topology settings yet, but more in how to set Azure endpoints or inter-datacentre communication to allow nodes to connect remotely. Do I need to set endpoint for node communication inside one datacentre?

What about security of azure endpoints?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm looking for answers as well: Do all the VMs need a public IP? Should the public IP be the listen_address? Should rpc_address be 0.0.0.0? Does ports 7000, 9160, 9042 need to be VM endpoints?

Comment: Check out this answer on a related question:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30096661/628904